# Как вычислить положение точки относительно выпуклого четырехугольника Java?

Tags: java

Нужен код, который позволит рассчитать положение точки относительно выпуклого четырехугольника в двумерном пространстве именно на Java. Может кто подскажет с чего хотя бы начать, а то совсем что то идей никаких.

Comment: В каком плане положение? Внутри/снаружи? Или указание расстояния до ближайшей стороны, например?

Comment: Скажем есть некоторые координаты четырехугольника, и далее нам дают координаты точки и надо определить, попадает эта точка в границы этого многоугольника или нет?

Comment: Ну хоть бы погуглили.  https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html не сильно от Java отличается

Comment: Так как многоугольник выпуклый, достаточно проверить, что точка лежит в каждом из углов многоугольника. То есть пусть у вас n вершин, вы должны пройти по каждой из них и проверить, что точка X лежит в угле A[i - 1]_A[i]_A[i + 1]. Чтобы проверить, что точка лежит в угле, можно использовать псевдовекторное произведение векторов. Чуть позже могу объяснить, если сами не найдете информацию.

Comment: EzikBro, если не сложно просветите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0):

Так как многоугольник выпуклый, достаточно проверить, что точка лежит в каждом из углов многоугольника. То есть пусть у вас `N` вершин, тогда вы должны пройти по каждой из них и проверить, что точка `X` лежит в угле `A[i - 1]_A[i]_A[i + 1]`, где A - массив координат вершин вашего многоугольника по порядку.

Чтобы проверить, что точка лежит в угле, можно использовать псевдоскалярное произведение векторов. Псевдоскалярное (косое) произведение векторов A и B - это число, равное `|A| * |B| * sin(alpha)`, где `alpha` - угол вращения против часовой стрелки от A до B. То есть для нахождения `alpha` вы можете построить данные вам вектора от одной точки и найти ориентированный(!) угол от A до B.

[image: Извиняюсь за такие великолепные рисунки, но что есть, то есть]

Также это прекрасное произведение очень просто вычисляется и без всяких измерений углов с помощью одних лишь координат: `A ^ B = Ax * By - Bx * Ay`. Получается, теперь, зная координаты, мы можем узнать и кое-какие сведения об угле, а именно - точное значение его синуса.

В прочем, в нашем случае точное значение нам не пригодится, а важен будет лишь знак. Заметим, что:

1. `sin(x) > 0` => `0 < x < 180` (градусов).
2. `sin(x) = 0` => `x = 0` или `x = 180`.
3. `sin(x) < 0` => `180 < x < 360`.

При этом псевдоскалярное произведение по знаку полностью совпадает со знаком синуса, а значит, что:

1. `A ^ B > 0` => B левее A.
2. `A ^ B = 0` => B коллинеарен с A.
3. `A ^ B < 0` => B правее A.

На этом вся польза от псевдоскалярного произведения на данный момент кончается, и мы можем перейти к самой задаче.

Примерный код алгоритма выглядит так:

```
double vectorMultiple(Vector a, Vector b)
    return a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y;

bool pointInAngle(Vector a, Vector b, Vector p) 
    if (vectorMultiple(a, b) < 0)
        return (vectorMultiple(a, p) < 0) && (vectorMultiple(p, b) < 0);
    return (vectorMultiple(b, p) < 0) && (vectorMultiple(p, a) < 0);

bool pointInAngle(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point p) // Point P in angle ABC
    Vector ba = Vector(b, a); // Vector AB = {B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y}
    Vector bc = Vector(b, c);
    Vector bp = Vector(b, p);
    return pointInAngle(ba, bc, bp);

bool pointInPolygon(Point[] poly, Point p)
    for (int i = 0; i < poly.length; i++)
        if (!pointInAngle(p, poly[i], poly[(i + 1) % poly.length], poly[(i + 2) % poly.length])
            return false;
    return true;
```

Также стоит отметить, что существует более быстрый алгоритм, работающий за O(logN), прочитать о котором можно, например, тут:
[https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=принадлежность_точки_выпуклому_и_невыпуклому_многоугольникам](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Однако, учитывая, что вам требуется решения только для четырехугольника, то используя данный алгоритм вы скорее всего даже потеряете в производительности, так что использовать его смысла нет.

Comment: Это просто легендарно!!! Спасибо вам огромное!! Очень выручили!!!